# change the class components to functional components for pageflip

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react and I am an intermediate level or so I think am trying to implement this book flip thingy which is provided by:

```
import HTMLFlipBook from "react-pageflip";
```

I tried to convert this to functional component but all to a melancholic ending, I couldn't, maybe coz I do not know nothing about class based components and I dont feel like learning it either since I already know the functional components.

```
const PageCover = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <div className="page page-cover" ref={ref} data-density="hard">
        <div className="page-content">
          <h2>{props.children}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  
  const Page = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <div className="page" ref={ref}>
        <div className="page-content">
          <h2 className="page-header">Page header - {props.number}</h2>
          <div className="page-image"></div>
          <div className="page-text">{props.children}</div>
          <div className="page-footer">{props.number + 1}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  
  class DemoBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        page: 0,
        totalPage: 0,
      };
    }
  
    nextButtonClick = () => {
      this.flipBook.getPageFlip().flipNext();
    };
  
    prevButtonClick = () => {
      this.flipBook.getPageFlip().flipPrev();
    };
  
    onPage = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        page: e.data,
      });
    };
  
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        totalPage: this.flipBook.getPageFlip().getPageCount(),
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <HTMLFlipBook
            width={550}
            height={733}
            size="stretch"
            minWidth={315}
            maxWidth={1000}
            minHeight={400}
            maxHeight={1533}
            maxShadowOpacity={0.5}
            showCover={true}
            mobileScrollSupport={true}
            onFlip={this.onPage}
            onChangeOrientation={this.onChangeOrientation}
            onChangeState={this.onChangeState}
            className="demo-book"
            ref={(el) => (this.flipBook = el)}
          >

            <PageCover>BOOK TITLE</PageCover>
            <Page number={1}>Lorem ipsum...</Page>
            <Page number={2}>Lorem ipsum...</Page>
            /*...*/
            <PageCover>THE END</PageCover>

          </HTMLFlipBook>
  
          <div className="container">
            <div>

              <button type="button" onClick={this.prevButtonClick}>
                Previous page
              </button>

              [<span>{this.state.page}</span> of
               <span>{this.state.totalPage}</span>]

              <button type="button" onClick={this.nextButtonClick}>
                Next page
              </button>

            </div>
            <div>

              State: <i>{this.state.state}</i>, orientation: <i>{this.state.orientation}</i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Can somebody help me achieve this same functionality using hooks and functional based components. Please

Comment: Is this snippet is working ? Please post the full code which you have tried and working with class based components

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS https://nodlik.github.io/react-pageflip/ and click on show sources for example

Comment: I have checked the source code its not the same where you can see the working example. Did you tried it

Comment: I tried converting the given code to functional components and tried doing it but i couldnt, spent few hours to rectify them but then again, i couldnt

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS do you know of any other react components that gives me the functionality of books? page turns and all

Comment: Nope, need to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225408/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-shrijal).

Comment: Do you want to convert  DemoBook class component to function component?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood what you meant.But to turn it into function component , I think it can be done...

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    function DemoBook () {
      const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
      const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(0);
    
     
      useEffect(() => {
       setTotalPage(this.flipBook.getPageFlip().getPageCount())
      });
    
      const   nextButtonClick = () => {
          this.flipBook.getPageFlip().flipNext();
        };
    const prevButtonClick = () => {
          this.flipBook.getPageFlip().flipPrev();
        };
    const  onPage = (e) => {
    setPage(e.data)
         
        };
     
    
      return (
        <div>
              <HTMLFlipBook
                width={550}
                height={733}
                size="stretch"
                minWidth={315}
                maxWidth={1000}
                minHeight={400}
                maxHeight={1533}
                maxShadowOpacity={0.5}
                showCover={true}
                mobileScrollSupport={true}
                onFlip={onPage}
                onChangeOrientation={this.onChangeOrientation}
                onChangeState={this.onChangeState}
                className="demo-book"
                ref={(el) => (this.flipBook = el)}
              >
    
                <PageCover>BOOK TITLE</PageCover>
                <Page number={1}>Lorem ipsum...</Page>
                <Page number={2}>Lorem ipsum...</Page>
                /*...*/
                <PageCover>THE END</PageCover>
    
              </HTMLFlipBook>
      
              <div className="container">
                <div>
    
                  <button type="button" onClick={prevButtonClick}>
                    Previous page
                  </button>
    
                  [<span>{this.state.page}</span> of
                   <span>{this.state.totalPage}</span>]
    
                  <button type="button" onClick={nextButtonClick}>
                    Next page
                  </button>
    
                </div>
                <div>
    
                  State: <i>{this.state.state}</i>, orientation: <i>{this.state.orientation}</i>
    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```